# Create marquee in nativescript

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

Using css I can create a simple `marquee` by adding animation to `left` property https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa . But I can't do the same with `nativescript` because it doesn't support `left` in animations yet https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation-css . So I'm trying to create the same animation using `transform` but I can't determine the exact `duration` and `transform` values since the `marquee` content will be created dynamically.

```
<AbsoluteLayout width="100%" class="marquee">
    <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" zIndex="89">
        <StackLayout id="lytAdvertisementBar" orientation="horizontal" class="advertisement-bar">
            <Label text="Random text is here"/>
            <Label class="fa-star" text="  &#xf005;  " style="color: #FFD42B;"></Label> 
            <Label text="Random text is here"/>
            <Label class="fa-star" text="  &#xf005;  " style="color: #FFD42B;"></Label> 
            <Label text="Random text is here"/>
            <Label class="fa-star" text="  &#xf005;  " style="color: #FFD42B;"></Label> 
            <Label text="Random text is here"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <Image src="res://icon_custom_offers" right="20" zIndex="99"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes kf-marquee {
    from { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
    to   { transform: translate(100%, 0); }
}

.advertisement-bar {
    transform:translateX(100%);
    animation-name: kf-marquee;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,1,1,1);
}
.marquee{
    background-color: #414042;
    width: 100%;
}
.advertisement-bar{
    left: 0;
    background-color: #414042;
    margin: 1 0;
    padding: 3 0;
}
```

How can I fix my code so I can have a `marquee` animation using css/js in nativescript, and have a constant speed for the animation(dynamic duration)?

Comment: Since your marquee content is dynamic, you may not be able to use declarative animation, use [Imperative](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation-code) with dynamic duration calculated based on [device width](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_platform_.screenmetrics#widthdips) vs [label width](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_label_.label#getmeasuredwidth).